# How many reviews should I get from the community to make my submitted subtitles to appear on others YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

How many reviews do I need from community to make my submitted subtitles to appear on others YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1):

Your content needs to be approved by the video owner.

As mentioned on [Google support](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6054623?hl=en-GB):

> Some channels let you contribute titles, descriptions, subtitles and closed captions to their videos. They're viewable on the video watch page and by clicking the [CC] icon in the player. **Approved content is controlled by the video owner, but you can get credit for your contributions on the video.**